# $S^{1}/∼$ is homeomorphic to $S^{1}$

Tags: general-topology

The equivalence relation $∼$ on $S^{1}$ is $x∼y$ iff $x+y=0$.

Show that $S^{1}/∼$ is homeomorphic to $S^{1}$.

Could $S^{1}/∼$ be the upper semicircle part that $(1,0)$ is closed and $(-1,0)$ is open?

My solution is here:Define a homeomorphism $h:S^{1} \rightarrow S^{1}/∼$ and 
$h(z)=[z]$ where $[z]=\{z,-z\}$

I talked to my professor then.He told me it's correct and I need to use Passing to the Quotient Theorem.Now I am totally confused.

I tried the theorem and did it this way,I'm not sure if it's right.
[image]

Comment: The function you defined is not injective. You have $h(z)=h(-z)$ for all $z\in S^1$.

Comment: $x\sim y$ under your definition is not an equivalence relation. $x\pm y=0$ is an equivalence relation.

Comment: There is a simple onto map $h:S^1\to S^1$ which satisfies $h(x)=h(y)$ iff $x\pm y=0$ and thus factors as $S^1\to S^1/\sim \to S^1.$

Comment: Try $h(z)=\{x\mid x^2=z\}.$

Comment: $x - y = 0 \implies x = y$?

Comment: @ Thomas Andrews I just talked to my friend and realized that the relation is not even valid.It should be x +/- y=0

Comment: @ Thomas Andrews I just edited it.Could you see if that is what you tried to direct me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct equivalence relation is defined by $x \sim y$ iff $x \pm y = 0$. Your definition is not an equivalence relation (since $x \not\sim x$).

$\sim$ identifies antipodal points of the circle, thus the quotient map $p : S^1  \to S^1/\sim$ is not injective and cannot be a homeomorphism. We claim that $S^1/\sim$ is a Hausdorff space. If $[x], [y]$ are distinct element of $S^1/\sim$, then the sets $p^{-1}([x]) = \{x,-x\}$ and  $p^{-1}([y]) = \{y,-y\}$ are disjoint subsets of $S^1$. Let $r$ be the minimum of $d(x,y) = d(-x,-y)$ and $d(x,-y) = d(-x,y)$. Here $d$ is the usual Euclidean metric. We have $r > 0$. Let $U_x =\{x' \in S^1 \mid d(x,x') < r/2 \}$ and $U_y =\{y' \in S^1 \mid d(y,y') < r/2 \}$. These are disjoint open neighborhoods of $x, y$. We have $p^{-1}(p(U_x)) = U_x  \cup -U_x$ with $-U_x = \{-x' \mid x' \in U_x \}$ which is open in $S^1$. Hence $p(U_x)$ is an open neighborhood of $[x]$ in $S^1/\sim$. Similarly $p(U_y)$ is an open neighborhood of $[y]$ in $S^1/\sim$. But we have $p(U_x) \cap p(U_y) = \emptyset$ since
$$p^{-1}(p(U_x) \cap p(U_y)) = p^{-1}(p(U_x)) \cap p^{-1}(p(U_y)) = (U_x  \cup -U_x) \cap (U_y  \cup -U_y) \\= U_x \cap U_y \cup U_x \cap (-U_y)\cup  (-U_x) \cap U_y \cup (-U_x) \cap (-U_y) = \emptyset .$$
Hence $S^1/\sim$ is a *compact Hausdorff space*.

If we interpret $S^1$ as the unit circle in the complex plane, then we see $z \sim z'$ iff $z = \pm z'$ iff $z^2 = (z')^2$. So let us consider the map $s : S^1 \to S^1, s(z) = z^2$. Then $s(z) = s(z')$ iff $z \sim z'$, hence $s$ induces a unique continuous map $s' : S^1/\sim \phantom{.} \to S^1$ such that $s' \circ p = s$ (universal property of the quotient topology). You have $s'([z] ) = z^2$, thus your approach is correct.

Since $s$ is surjective, also $s'$ is surjective. Morever we have $s'([z]) = s([z])$ iff $z^2 = (z')^2$ iff $[z] = [z']$. Hence $s'$ is injective. Thus $s'$ is a continuous bijection between compact Hausdorff spaces and therefore a homeomorphism.

Comment: To stretch things somewhat, it would have been correct to say that $x+y=0$ *generates* the required equivalence relation.

Comment: Would just using h([z])=z^2 be a homeomorphism?

Comment: Yes, this is what I used. You must of course prove that it is well-defined, continuous etc. This is the lengthy part.

Comment: @Paul Frost Thank you! I think my prof meant x+/-y=0 but carelessly made mistake on definition of ~ .

Comment: @XYC You are certainly right. See Lee Mosher's comment. If you say that $x \sim y$ if (not **iff**) $x + y = 0$, then everbody will understand that you mean the equivalence relation generated by that.

Comment: @ Lee Mosher Are you saying that x+y=0 is necessarily enough to be a condition of the question?

Comment: @Paul Frost  In the original questions,it mentions that $S^1$ is in complex plane with radius $1$ and equivalence relation ~ is defined on $S^1$ by $x$ ~ $ y \,$ $\mathbf{iff}$ $x+y=0$.

Comment: @XYC If you define $x \sim y$ **iff** $x+y=0$, then it is definitely not an equivalence relation.